# Autocad selection filter in design automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-designautomation

Hi I am prototyping an Autocad Design Automation project from an old desktop script. I used a selection filter before I realized that window selection etc don't work if it is off-screen. Design Automation by definition should be an 'off-screen' application, I think? Then I will have to loop through the whole database? Any other way to get around, please? I need to find a solution before too far off track...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your script with accoreconsole.exe (it is in the autocad installation folder) on your local machine. There's still a window although invisible so selection should work as in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 1):

you are correct with the understanding that Design Automation is off-screen. So the section of user interactive will not work on cloud engine. While windows selection of AutoCAD can input the windows points in code. e.g. in Design Automation scripts, define as below:

```
    select w -150,150,0 150,-150,0 \n
```

It will select all entities that within the windows of the two corners. I used local Accoreconsole to demo (attached snapshot) .  Accoreconsole  is an off-screen environment on local. It is similar to Design Automation engine.

[image]

If your workflow does not know where the user may select, it will be not either possible to Design Automation to perform the action.